# Check if array contain value from outside another array php

Tags: php, arrays

I have this two arrays

```
Array_1 ( [0] => 5836 [1] => 5837 )
Array_2 ( [0] => 5837 [1] => 2836 [2] => 2836 )
```

I want to check if **array_2** has value that it's not contain in **array_1** like **2836, 2836**

I have try **in_array** and **array_intersection** not gave me what I need

Comment: Then what _do_ you actually need? It is not really clear, what actual result you want to get.

Comment: Try `array_diff()`.

Comment: Not working output :

Array ( [0] => 5836 )

Comment: _"Not working output : Array ( [0] => 5836 )"_ - the _order_ is important, the difference from array 1 to array 2, is something else than the difference from array 2 to array 1 - https://3v4l.org/PVNel

Comment: yes sorry the problem is in ordering, it's right thank you

Answer (score 0):

Using `in_array()`

```
$Array_1 = [5836, 5837];
$Array_2 = [5837, 2836, 2836];

foreach($Array_2 as $a2){
    if ( ! in_array($a2, $Array_1)){
        echo "$a2 is not in Array_1\n";
    }
}
```

RESULT

```
2836 is not in Array_1
2836 is not in Array_1
```

Using `array_diff()` NOTE: The order is important

```
$Array_1 = [5836, 5837];
$Array_2 = [5837, 2836, 2836];
print_r(array_diff($Array_2, $Array_1));
```

RESULT, do with it what you like

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2836
    [2] => 2836
)
```

Comment: Solve :), by first solution that what I want it.

Thank You